# Why is it not an error to call a non-parameterized method with type arguments?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following Java program that I was expecting to not compile, but it did:

```
class Test {
    public static void f() {
    }

    void m() {
            Test.<String>f();
    }
}
```

Why does javac allow calling a non-parameterized method in this way?

My Java compiler version is: javac 1.7.0_75

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? It does not compile to me (JDK 1.5 and1.6)

Comment: @Albert Oh, I am using Java 7. I will edit the description with my JDK version.

Comment: From where you got this stuff  ⁿ|ⁿ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The explicit type parameter is simply ignored.

This is stated in [JLS, Section 15.12.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1):

> - If the method invocation includes explicit type arguments, and the member is a generic method, then the number of type arguments is equal
>     to the number of type parameters of the method.
>
> *This clause implies that a non-generic method may be potentially
>   applicable to an invocation that supplies explicit type arguments.
>   Indeed, it may turn out to be applicable. **In such a case, the type
>   arguments will simply be ignored.***